# SNMP what is the max length for DisplayString

Tags: snmp

What is the max length that i can have in MIB of syntax DisplayString (SNMPv2)

```
openConnectionsList OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      DisplayString
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
            "The textual"
    ::= {  MONITOR-MIB 2 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNMPv2?

255

http://ipmsupport.solarwinds.com/mibs/SNMPV2-TC/item.aspx?tid=DisplayString

Comment: I create my own mib module and i have no problem to define it there as static char connections_list_value[1024]; and i didnt have problem to call get and set with 1024 chars

Comment: @user1495181, the problem of your own overriding is that except your own objects, all other objects are still using 255 as maximum, where you introduce unnecessary incompatibility. If you don't like the limit, create your own type of DisplayString, such as MyLongDisplayString. Never override an existing type especially when that type is widely used elsewhere.